# Do <img> or <canvas> hold a reference to original (large) dataUrl object?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Given image data stored as a dataUrl and passed from a variable to an image or canvas background, will the dom elements hold a reference to the original js dataUrl in memory?

I'm asking because if the reference breaks, it would be a very good idea to allow garbage collection. If the reference holds anyway, I can keep the dataUrl on the visual component in js for eventual later re-use without duplication.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data-uris are strings and as strings are not reference values, the value is copied to src. There is no reference to the original data-uri (this also applies to ordinary URLs for that matter, as the src property can only take strings).

Answer (score 0):

It is stored in memory in a sense that the canvas element is the emulation of the string to an image. Once a canvas element is created, you can use the native canvas method .toDataURL to get the string url of the canvas element. This should be the original string you passed in.